# Connection Pool Behavior ODP.NET

Tags: oracle, connection-pooling, odp.net

I'm trying to work out the behavior of connection pooling with ODP.NET. I get the basics but I don't understand what's happening. I have an application that spins up threads every X seconds and that thread connects and performs a number of searches against the database then disconnects, everything is being disposed and disconnected as you would expect. With the defaults in the connection string and X set to a high number that ensures searches are complete before the next search takes place, I get an exception, not on connect, as I would have expected but on OracleDataAdapter.Fill(). I get the following exception:

```
'ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1 ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded'
```

After the 9th connection. Every time. Then, the application will run indefinitely without another error. It's definitely related to connection pooling. If I turn off pooling it works without error. If I turn Min Pool Size up then it takes longer for the error but it eventually happens.

My expectation for connection pooling would be a wait on the call to connect to get a new connection, not Fill failing on an adapter that's already connected (although I get that the connection object is using a pool, so maybe that's not what's happening). Anyway it's odd behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is not relating to a maximum number of connections but a maximum number of cursors.

A cursor is effectively a pointer to a memory address within the database server that lets the server look up the query the cursor is executing and the current state of the cursor.

Your code is connecting and then opening cursors but, for whatever reason, it is not closing the cursors. When you close a connection it will automatically close all the cursors; however, when you return a connection to a connection pool it keeps the connection open so it can be reused (and because it does not close the connection it does not automatically close all the cursors).

It is best-practice to make sure that when you open a cursor it is closed when you finish reading from it and if there is an error during the execution of the cursor, that prevents the normal execution path, then that the cursor is closed when you catch the exception.

You need to debug your code and make sure you close all the cursors you open.

Comment: Yeah, I get that, but I'm not interacting directly with cursors, I'm interacting with connections and the connection pool. All my connections and other objects are being closed. If I turn off connection pooling I get zero issues, even running with hundreds of connections. Also, why does this happen so early in the operation, and only once per run? If something wasn't being closed properly it would keep happening, not once in tens of thousands of connections, and then never again. It's almost like the connection pool isn't initialized properly, something jolts it into action, and then it works

Comment: I can get around it with settings and retries but it's yet another Oracle oddity to deal with.